Issue with Token Generation in ASP.NET Core 8 using Azure AD B2C: Error AADSTS50049
I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 8 API called ApiApp secured with Azure AD B2C and an ASP.NET Core MVC application called WebApp. Everything works fine, and I can call ApiApp from WebApp.
I want to enrich the user's claims using IClaimsTransformation upon login. My goal is to implement IClaimsTransformation, make a call to ApiApp to query the database, retrieve the necessary data, and enrich the user's claims.
To achieve this, I need a token to call ApiApp. I tried generating the token with the following method:
private async Task<string> GetApplicationTokenAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var clientId = _configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"]; // ClientId of the WebApp
        var clientSecret = _configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientSecret"]; // ClientId of the WebApp
        var scope = _configuration["MyApp:MyAppScope"]; // exposed API scope access_as_user
        var tenant = _configuration["AzureAdB2C:Domain"];
        var policy = _configuration["AzureAdB2C:SignUpSignInPolicyId"];

        var tenantName = "mytenant";
        var authority = $"https://{tenantName}.b2clogin.com/{tenantName}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/v2.0";


        var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .WithAuthority(new Uri(authority))
            .Build();

        var authResult = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(new[] { scope }).ExecuteAsync();
        return authResult.AccessToken;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

However, I receive the error:

AADSTS50049: "Unknown or invalid instance".


What should I do to correctly obtain the token?
Is there something wrong in my Azure AD B2C configuration or code?


REPO:
I have created this repository to facilitate clear visibility and analysis of the issue I am encountering, allowing for a deeper understanding of the error.

Azure ApiApp Config:

API permissions
Expose an API
I have 1 Certificate & secret
Authentication


Azure WebApp Config:

Authentication
I have 1 Certificate & secret
API permissions
In the Expose an API section I have nothing


could you make sure that your ApiApp has the correct API permissions. check if you have defined the scope (e.g., api://{clientId}/access_as_user) in the Azure portal. Make sure the WebApp has permission to request this scope.

try setting the appsettings.json file like this:{   "AzureAdB2C": {     "Instance": "https://your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/",     "ClientId": "your-client-id",     "Domain": "your-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com",     "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "your-policy-name",     "ClientSecret": "your-client-secret"   },   "MyApp": {     "MyAppScope": "api://your-api-app-client-id/access_as_user"   } }

@JalpaPanchal I updated my question with more data about my Azure Ad configurations. I can confirm that I have the correct API permissions(api://{clientId}/access_as_user)

@JalpaPanchal also I tried to set the appsettings.json file as you suggested, but I get always the same error. At his point maybe the problem is authority. This is how the  var authority it looks like :  $"https://myapp.b2clogin.com/myapp.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SignUpSignIn/oauth2/v2.0/token"`

the authority url format looks like not in correct format could you try this: https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/v2.0. double check the all values in your appsettings.json are correct. try to use the postman to get the token using same configuration to troubleshoot the issue
